# scala code causes error in eclipse for playframework-2.0

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, playframework-2.0

I am trying out the `todolist tutorial` of `playframework-2.0`  on eclipse.I `eclipsified` the code and imported it sothat `eclipse(helios)` can detect the play api properly.I am however having trouble with the `scala` part

I updated eclipse to get the scala ide plugin .Still  eclipse shows error markers next to

```
return ok(views.html.index.render(Task.all(),taskForm));
```

The error popup box shows `views.html.index cannot be resolved to a type`

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: the app compiles and runs ok outside of eclipse?

Comment: could you check that the folder `scala-2.9.1/src_managed` is set as sources folder and the folder `scala-2.9.1/classes_managed` is added to the classpath of your Eclipse Project ?

Comment: @opensas ,it compiles and runs outside eclipse..

Comment: @andypetrella ,I have added the folder `todolist/target/scala-2.9.1/classes_managed` to the `libraries` using `AddClassFolder` button .The `source folder` list now has `todolist/app` ,`todolist/target/scala-2.9.1/src_managed` and `todolist/test`

Comment: and still shown as errored ? Maybe closing and reopening the project (kind of force refresh) might correct the problem. Because if you check under `todolist/target/scala-2.9.1/classes_managed/views/html/` you should see the `index*` class files

Comment: sometimes it helps to issue a play clean-all, play clean, play compile...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the [Setup and use Play framework in Scala IDE](http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/play/index.html) tutorial. For any trouble, bug us on the [scala-ide-user](https://groups.google.com/group/scala-ide-user) ML.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the solution was to add the /target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main folder to the classpath.

Comment: This worked for me. I had to add /target/scala-2.12/classes_managed instead of the path you gave in your answer, but this made the error go away

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get rid of this warning by eclipsifying the project again

```
play eclipse
```

or

```
activator eclipse # If you use activator
```