# Play! framework - views aren't compiled?

Tags: java, web, webserver, playframework-2.0

I created a new project and working with eclipse (used `eclipsify` command).
basically, I moved the `app` directory from an old project to the new one I created.

the problem is that eclipse doesn't recognize the views. I get errors like:

> views.html.viewTopic cannot be resolved to a type

I tried to `play compile` but it didn't help.
so I got 40 errors. all of them connected to the fact that the views aren't compiled and therefore, the eclipse doesn't recognize them (my guess of course).

**what can I do?**
by the way, the old project compiled and ran without a problem (I used intellij)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Playframework - Eclipse can't detect a new template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739119/playframework-eclipse-cant-detect-a-new-template)

Comment: Also, make sure Eclipse is refreshing filesystem changes automatically. See: http://scala-ide.org/docs/tutorials/play20scalaide20/index.html ("Configure Eclipse so changes on the file system are automatically picked up")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can do is just search the Stack Overflow as this topic was discussed really many times.

- [Playframework - Eclipse can't detect a new template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739119)
- [How to make Eclipse see the changes in Play! compiled templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10042987)
- [scala code causes error in eclipse for playframework-2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960538)
- etc, etc...

Comment: ok, I've seen something strange. in `src_managed` directory there is no `models` directory although there should be. there's only `controllers` and `views`. why is that?

Comment: Did you check what `controllers` and `views` contains? most prbably in first you have only `routes.java` - in second html files compiled into scala functions. There are no controller's or model's classes, so yes it looks normal.

Comment: I run the command `play idea` and now using intellij but still, same problem. intellij does not recognize those views.html files.

Comment: Really strange, I'm working with Idea and it recognizes views just view seconds after recompiling

Comment: this is what I did. I created a new project. after that, I copied an old `app` directory (with all the sub-dirs - views, models, controllers). I compiled and ran the project. very strange indeed...

Answer (score 5):

For Java Play Framework v2.4.6 (activator v1.3.7) with Eclipse Mars:

So that you will not have a "can not resolve error" with your `viewTopic.render()`, you can add this `<classpathentry kind="lib" path="target/scala-2.11/classes"/>` to your `.classpath` or right-click on your project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Add Class Folder and make it point to `target/scala-2.11/classes`.

Comment: You are great.. I have tried to solve this problem for more than 2 hours and your solution works :)

Answer (score 3):

- Run 'play eclipse' on the command line
- In Eclipse, refresh your Project via hitting F5

Answer (score 2):

Re-run the command in play console with the sources this time:
$ eclipse with-source=true

And then go to eclipse and clean your project and build all

Answer (score 1):

According to jetbrains, the issue with templates is fixed. If you have play 2 generated source sources included in the IDEA project then you should exclude this folder from the project

http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-folders-within-a-content-root.html

and do File | Invalidate caches and restart.

If you have an SBT project, open it in IDEA via File | Import Project | Sbt type project

Make sure to use the latest Scala and Play 2 plugins.

Answer (score 1):

1. Close eclipse project
2. activator eclipse
3. activator compile
4. Open eclipse project
5. Add target/scala-[your-version-here]/classes to your build path as a class folder

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved it.

- I created a new app again
- moved `app` dir
- **only then** ran the command `play idea`