# Error downloading and compiling play-mailer plugin

Tags: plugins, playframework, mailer

I'm wrecking my brain on trying to get this plugin downloaded and compiled into my application.

```
$ activator --version
sbt launcher version 0.13.8

playVersion: 2.4.6
scalaVersion: 2.11.6
```

`build.sbt` file is:

```
import sbt.Keys._

name := """hrm"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(play.PlayJava, PlayEbean)

scalaVersion := "2.11.6"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  javaJdbc,
  cache,
  javaWs,
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "3.0.1",
  "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m",
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.38",
  filters
)

resolvers ++= Seq(
    "Apache" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/",
    "jBCrypt Repository" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/",
    "Sonatype OSS Snasphots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"
)

// Play provides two styles of routers, one expects its actions to be injected, the
// other, legacy style, accesses its actions statically.
routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator


fork in run := true
```

My `plugins.sbt` is:

```
// Comment to get more information during initialization
logLevel := Level.Warn

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Cloudbees
resolvers += "Sonatype OSS Snasphots" at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots"

// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.6")

// Web plugins
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.6")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.3")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.7")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.1.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.1.0")

// Play enhancer - this automatically generates getters/setters for public fields
// and rewrites accessors of these fields to use the getters/setters. Remove this
// plugin if you prefer not to have this feature, or disable on a per project
// basis using disablePlugins(PlayEnhancer) in your build.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-enhancer" % "1.1.0")

// Play Ebean support, to enable, uncomment this line, and enable in your build.sbt using
// enablePlugins(PlayEbean). Note, uncommenting this line will automatically bring in
// Play enhancer, regardless of whether the line above is commented out or not.
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
```

in `play.plugins` I have:

```
1500:play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailerPlugin
```

Still, I can't get to download the plugin and compile and run the app.

What am I missing here?

**UPDATE 1:** Actually, Eclipse says MailerClient, part of `play.libs.mailer.MailerClient` cannot be resolved. Like this:
[image]

It might be due the previous error, where the html file `password.scala.html` cannot be resolved in:

```
import views.html.account.settings.password;
```

And I tried to move this line further below to no change...

Comment: Could you please add the error message as well?

Comment: @Roman Please, see the update.

Comment: Try to remove `1500:play.api.libs.mailer.CommonsMailerPlugin
` in `play.plugins`. According to the [docs](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer) this is not required in version 3. When running `sbt run`, can the dependency be resolved or do you get any errors?

Comment: I removed the said line from the `play.plugins` butI still get errors. These errors seem to be related to the lack of the compiled views, though.

Comment: I managed to get the `play.libs.mailer.*` problems solved by issuing `$ activator eclipse with-source=true`, as per suggested on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12529489/play-framework-views-arent-compiled